# How can I share config file like appsettings.json across multiple ASP.NET CORE projects in one solution in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I have 3 ASP.NET CORE projects in one solution and I want to share connection string information in one config file like appsettings.json across these projects.

How can I do this in Visual Studio 2015 ?

Answer (score 17):

You can use absolute path on each project like this(I assume `appsettings.json` file is in the solution root directory(like global.json) ):

```
var settingPath = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(@"../../appsettings.json")); // get absolute path
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile(settingPath);
```

see https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/issues/440

Comment: [Andrew Lock](https://andrewlock.net/sharing-appsettings-json-configuration-files-between-projects-in-asp-net-core/) has a work around to also publish your shared settings.

Answer (score 6):

Set the absolute path to the shared appsettings.json file.

```
var relativePath = @"../../The/Relative/Path";
var absolutePath = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(relativePath);
```

Then use a `IFileProvider` like this.

```
var fileProvider = 
    new Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider(absolutePath);

_configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(_env.ContentRootPath)
    .AddJsonFile(fileProvider, $"appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
    .Build();
```

Or use `SetBasePath` like this.

```
var relativePath = @"../../The/Relative/Path";
var absolutePath = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(relativePath);

_configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(absolutePath)
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
    .Build();
```

Both will work, though the file provider approach allows the app to use its content root as the base path for other static content. Adem's approach is also good.

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to use [user secrets](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/app-secrets.html) and have the apps share the same app id.

As a bonus, you get the keep the connection strings outside of your app and decrease the chances that they will leak because they were pushed in source control.

Answer (score 2):

There may be a better way to do this, but you could achieve this by adding a precompile setting to the project.json file.  Something similar to:

```
"scripts": {
  "precompile": [ "../copycommand.bat" ]
}
```

Where the `copycommand` points to a batch command that copies your AppSettings.json file into the current directory.  If you're targeting multiple platforms, you'll likely need to customise the command for each of the platforms.

Answer (score 1):

Add a shared project containing the appsettings.json files set to 'Copy if newer' and reference from the other projects.

Comment: this solution is not working in .NET 6 RC 2