# Dotnet Core 3.1: How to use AddJsonFile with absolute path to file?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I have a dotnet app in which I need to pull in configuration from both relative paths (the regular `appsettings.Json`, `appsettings.Development.json`), and also, from the absolute path `/config/appsettings.json`. I can't find a way to do this. From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.jsonconfigurationextensions.addjsonfile?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1), the path arg is `Path relative to the base path stored in Properties of builder.` How can I set it up to read a config from absolute path `/config/filename.json`?

Motivation:
I'm dockerizing the dotnet app, so I am planning to keep configuration that won't *usually* change between deployments in the regular `publish/appsettings.json` and deploy specific config in `/config/appsettings.json` (which is a volume I'll mount on the container at deploy time).

Comment: Did you check this question [How can I share config file like appsettings.json across multiple ASP.NET CORE projects in one solution in Visual Studio 2015?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38286704/how-can-i-share-config-file-like-appsettings-json-across-multiple-asp-net-core-p/38288754)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can edit your `CreateHostBuilder` method like this:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
{
    var builder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args);
    builder.ConfigureAppConfiguration(cfgBuilder =>
       {
           var provider = new PhysicalFileProvider("/config"); // Create a dedicated FileProvider based on the /config directory
           cfgBuilder.AddJsonFile(provider, "filename.json", true, true); // Add the filename.json configuration file stored in the /config directory
       });
    builder.ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
       {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
       });

    return builder;
}
```

Comment: Haven't actually tried yet, but pretty sure it'll work. Thanks!

Comment: Does this work for anyone? I get this error when I try to create a PhysicalFileProvider with a relative path: "System.ArgumentException: 'The path must be absolute. Arg_ParamName_Name'

Comment: @RobinBennett please note that this answer is relative to linux environment,. "/config" is an absolute path there. If you are willing to run on Windows and want to use a relative path make sure to transform it to an absolute one (for example by calling System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(yourRelativePath))

Answer (score 2):

[agnivesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7833391/agnivesh) Try this snippet code example:

```
        public static class AppConfigurations
        {
            private static IConfigurationRoot BuildConfiguration(this IWebHostEnvironment env)
            {
                var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                    .AddJsonFile("config/appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
                //
                //  TODO
                //
                return builder.Build();
            }
        }
```

Now call this class function in Startup class contructor:

```
public Startup(IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        _appConfiguration = env.BuildConfiguration();
    }
```

Comment: I am using DefaultWebHostBuilder. Can't control the whole config. Also, I think `config/appsettings.json` will look for {contentrootpath}/config/appsettings.json

Answer (score 0):

I use a trick.. "relative path", but the parent... you can use "../"

Comment: "../" doesn't work for me, and annoyingly it doesn't tell me _what_ path it's looking for, while `.AddJsonFile("nonexistentfile.json")` will very helpfully tell me that it didn't find that file and show me the absolute path it used.